# caching in WCF web service

Tags: c#, cache, wcf

I want to realize caching in WCF web service. I'm using the following code:

```
public interface ICache<T> : IDisposable where T : class
    {
        string Name { get; }
        CacheItemPolicy CacheItemPolicy { get; set; }
        long Count { get; }
        bool IsDisposed { get; }
        void AddOrUpdate(string key, T value);
        bool TryGetValue(string key, out T value);
        T GetValue(string key);
        bool TryRemove(string key, out T value);
        void Remove(string key);
        bool ContainsKey(string key);
    }

public class MemoryCacheWrapper<T> : ICache<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly MemoryCache _memoryCache;
        private CacheItemPolicy _cacheItemPolicy;
        private bool _isDisposed;

        public MemoryCacheWrapper(string name, NameValueCollection config = null)
        {
            _memoryCache = config != null ? new MemoryCache(name, config) : new MemoryCache(name);
            _isDisposed = false;                
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _memoryCache.Name; }
        }

        public long CacheMemoryLimitInBytes
        {
            get { return _memoryCache.CacheMemoryLimit; }
        }

        public long PhysicalMemoryLimit
        {
            get { return _memoryCache.PhysicalMemoryLimit; }
        }

        public TimeSpan PollingInterval
        {
            get { return _memoryCache.PollingInterval; }
        }

        public CacheItemPolicy CacheItemPolicy
        {
            get
            {
                return _cacheItemPolicy;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    _cacheItemPolicy = value;
                }
            }
        }

        public void AddOrUpdate(string key, T value)
        {
            _memoryCache.Set(key, value, CacheItemPolicy);
        }

        public bool TryGetValue(string key, out T value)
        {
            bool result = false;
            value = default(T);

            object item = _memoryCache.Get(key);
            if (item != null)
            {
                value = (T)item;
                result = true;
            }

            return result;
        }

        public T GetValue(string key)
        {
            return (T)_memoryCache.Get(key);
        }

        public bool TryRemove(string key, out T value)
        {
            bool result = false;
            value = default(T);

            object item = _memoryCache.Remove(key);
            if (item != null)
            {
                result = true;
                value = (T)item;
            }

            return result;
        }

        public void Remove(string key)
        {
            _memoryCache.Remove(key);
        }

        public bool ContainsKey(string key)
        {
            return _memoryCache.Contains(key);
        }

        public long Count
        {
            get { return _memoryCache.GetCount(); }
        }

        ~MemoryCacheWrapper()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        private void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this._isDisposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    _memoryCache.Dispose();
                }
            }
            _isDisposed = true;
        }

        public bool IsDisposed
        {
            get { return _isDisposed; }
        }
    }
```

This is my service:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    public class PremieraInteraction : IPremieraInteraction
    {
        private ICache<InfoLevel> _cacheInfoLevel = new MemoryCacheWrapper<InfoLevel>("MyCache");

        public string GetPlacesInfoForSession(int levelId, int clientId, int sessionId)
        {
            var key = CacheUtils.GenerateKeyForCache(JobName.PlacesInfoForSession.ToString(),clientId, sessionId, levelId);
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            InfoLevel cachedInfoLevel;
            if (_cacheInfoLevel.TryGetValue(key, out cachedInfoLevel))
                return serializer.Serialize(new { Success = true, Count = cachedInfoLevel.AllPlacesCount, Free = cachedInfoLevel.FreePlaces });

            return serializer.Serialize(new { Success = false, Message = "Some error" });
        }
    }
```

What you think about this code?
This is not bad that I create `MemoryCacheWrapper` inside service and not static?
Also, `MemoryCacheWrapper` are generic. In the future, I need to create several `MemoryCacheWrapper` instances:

```
    private ICache<InfoLevel> _cacheInfoLevel = new MemoryCacheWrapper<InfoLevel>("MyCache");
    private ICache<OtherObject> _cacheOtherObject= new MemoryCacheWrapper<OtherObject>("MyCache");
```

Any suggestions are helpful.

Comment: Are you self-hosting the service or are you using IIS to host the service?

Comment: @Kane: I'm using IIS. Sorry fo delay.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have created an unuseful abstraction. Mostly your methods only calling the underlaying MemoryCache instance and you have created something weird: IDisposable wrapper over a static instance. Of yourse the MemoryCache can be disposed but not this way. You have a service with InstanceContextMode.Single then you should only call dispose or provide oppurtunity to call the Dispose method when your service stops.

Insted of your wrapper i would create some extension method for the typed get/remove logic wrappings:

```
public static class MemoryCacheExtensions
{
    public static bool TryGetValue<T>(this MemoryCache _memoryCache, string key, out T value)
    {
        var item = _memoryCache.Get(key);
        if (item != null)
        {
            value = (T)item;
            return true;
        }

        value = default(T);
        return false;
    }

    public static T GetValue<T>(this MemoryCache _memoryCache, string key)
    {
        return (T)_memoryCache.Get(key);
    }

    public static bool TryRemove<T>(this MemoryCache _memoryCache, string key, out T value)
    {
        var item = _memoryCache.Remove(key);
        if (item != null)
        {
            value = (T)item;
            return true;
        }
        value = default(T);
        return result;
    }
}
```